# AdSense won't approve application: "Site down or unavailable" even though the site is up

Tags: google-adsense

This is the website: howtoplaystation.com that I try to run ads on by Adsense.
First I had to add more content, I did.
But now I get the error four times in a row:
"Site unreachable or unavailable" But my site is accessible and available.
"We cannot find the code on your site. The code may be missing or incomplete, or the URL of your site may be incorrect," it also says, but I also added the code.
Please help me. Thanks for that.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to load your website, https://www.howtoplaystation.com in Chrome and it works well.

But I tried to load the URL: https://howtoplaystation.com in Chrome it throws me an error.

[image]

From the above image, the **non-www** version of your website throws the invalid SSL error.

In Adsense the section of "**my sites**", You tried to add the non-www version link and generated the Adsense code. That Adsense code will load your non-www version and will face the above error. So you notified as "**Website is down or not reachable**".

### **Two Way To Fix This Issue:**

1. Redirect your non-www version to www version (https://howtoplaystation.com  to https://www.howtoplaystation.com)
2. Remove the URL from the "mysites" & add the www version of your website for Adsense approval.

I personally suggest the 1st solution than the second one.

Comment: I hope now will be able to find out the issue that you are facing with Adsense Approval :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason behind the issue!. You placed the code wrongly:

The Script must be like this:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

But you pasted like this

```
<script> async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

You mistakenly added the "**>**" before the `async src=""`

The correct auto ads script for your website is:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4770171655971317",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>
```

Copy the above script and replace with the old one. This error will remove from your ads account!.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that I had also pasted the code like you say, but it didn't work either. When I paste the correct code: <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: "ca-pub-4770171655971317",
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script> It becomes:

Comment: it becomes: <script async='async' src='https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'/>
<script>
     (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
          google_ad_client: &quot;ca-pub-4770171655971317&quot;,
          enable_page_level_ads: true
     });
</script>

Comment: so actually it adds async='async' and changes " to &quot

Comment: and people told me to add the ">" before the async src=""

Comment: Adding ">" before the async won't work, add the AdSense provided code and wait for the approval.

Comment: yes, I tried that 5 times. Still showing the same error. Its already 2 weeks that I try.

Comment: I found a new issue on your site, That may be the cause for the non-approval of Adsense!

Comment: and what is the new issue?

Comment: Kindly check the "New Answer" that I mentioned in below thread.